# Lógica para o uso de chave estrangeira - notas de um usuário

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Estou encucado com um problema no uso de chave estrangeira. Não consigo achar a lógica para um sistema:

O problema: o usuário dá uma nota para cada quesito, cada um sendo um campo da tabela, e no final a média é calculada e inserida no banco de dados. Porém essa nota, assim como a média é cumulativa, ou seja, o segundo usuário dará suas notas e será somada com a avaliação do usuário 1, dividida e assim será gerada a média. Não estou conseguindo entender como conseguirei recuperar as notas e a média dada pelo usuário 1. Alguém pode me ajudar só com a lógica, por favor.

[image: tabela "estabelecimento"]

[image: tabela "usuario"]

Comment: Altera tua pergunta mostrando como está seu banco de dados

Comment: Adicionei a imagem

Comment: Me diz uma coisa: nessa tabela que você postou já tem um `idUser` e `media`. No caso, não seria apenas fazer um `select media from tabela where idUser = 1`?

Comment: Reformule sua pergunta, vou responder porque acho que entendi mas como foi montada não está claro o funcionamento. lembre-se você está envolvido nesse contexto outros usúarios não!

Comment: Eu não sei se sou eu que estou complicando a coisa ou realmente é só isso. O id user é para ser a chave estrangeira do id user de uma tabela chamada usuários. Caso eu faça o comando acima de selecionar a média, ele retornará a média dada por aquela usuário e não a média cumulativa, isso?

Comment: Vou editar aqui

Comment: estou respondendo ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa ter uma tabela para Usuário e uma para a Nota, está nota deverá ter uma chave estrangeira (O Id do usuário). Assim, um usuário terá muitas notas e uma nota apenas um usuário, quando quiser saber sobre uma determinada nota basta fazer uma query utilizando o dado da nota + id do usuário.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: E teria que ter também uma chave estrangeira para o código do estabelecimento, certo? Já que cada estabelecimento terá uma média das notas.

Obs: as notas individuais também deverão aparecer.

Comment: Exato! Pesquise um pouco sobre MER (Modelo Entidade Relacionamento) é um método utilizado para planejar um banco de dados, existem algumas técnicas para identificar quais são as entidades e relacionamentos do seu banco e o que vira tabela no banco físico

Comment: Procure no google sobre DER é um diagrama que facilita o entendimento da estrutura de um banco de dados....

Comment: 1º Passo – Definição de Escopo
Definir o contexto a ser trabalhado. Quanto menor o escopo, mais assertivo será o modelo. Ex: Marcar uma consulta.
2º Passo – Identificar as Entidades
Necessário levantar três questões sobre o Escopo:
O que é importante? Ex: Médico, Paciente, Consulta, etc.
Quais são os atributos (características)?
Ele é forte? Ou seja, objetos que não dependem de outros para existir, exemplo: médico e paciente.

A partir disso é possível definir as entidades do Escopo, como no exemplo médico e paciente são entidades dentro desse contexto.

Answer (score 0):

Se um produto tem N quesitos então na modelagem se supõem que temos que ter 2 tabelas uma para produtos e outras para quesitos porque essa é uma relação chamada de 1:N ou seja:

> Um produto pode ter N quesitos.

Nesse caso na tabela quesitos você vai ter que colocar uma coluna com o id_produto para especificar a nota por cada produto que foi avaliado e portanto se utilizou a chave primaria da tabela produtos em outra tabela essa deve ser um índice FK chamada em português de chave estrangeira.

Finalizando sempre que quiser calcular a média de um produto basta fazer um querie na tabela quesitos procurando pelo campo id_produto especifico que quer calcular e o id_quesito.

Utilize o comando AVG NO SQL para já ter a média do produto especificado.  Ou Utilize SUM para somar as notas e dividir pelo pela quantidade total de usuarios que avaliaram aquele quesito

https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_avg.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_mysql_sum.asp

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim para média do usuário 1:

`select media from TABELA where idUser = 1`

Para pegar a média de todos:

`select (sum(media) / count(*)) as mediatotal from TABELA`